# What does na.rm=TRUE actually means?

Tags: r

Whenever we have NA in our data,we used na.rm=TRUE to get proper results for mean,mode etc. What does na.rm do? I could understand that rm is for remove,which we even use for deleting variables.But why have we written na in small? R is case sensitive?And what does Boolean value TRUE does here?

Comment: As a side note, while I use that argument to `r`e`m`ove the `na` values from data, there are times when one might prefer to *not* remove them. For instance, if an assertion (in some process) is that there is no missing data, then I suggest `na.rm=TRUE` should not be used, since in the best-case it (1) is a no-op, does nothing; but quite possibly (2) masks a problem with the assumptions of input data. Just a thought.

Comment: I want to emphasize even more than the current answer does that *there's nothing special about `na.rm`*. It's just an argument name. Many functions take it, and implement it somehow, and many more don't. New R users often see it in so many common functions and think it must work in any function, but this is not the case. It works in the functions that implement it, and it doesn't work in the functions that don't. Every function that accepts a `na.rm` argument is free to interpret it however it wants.

Answer (score 13):

Argument `na.rm` gives a simple way of removing missing values from data if they are coded as `NA`. In base R its standard default value is `FALSE`, meaning, `NA`'s are not removed.

Consider the following vector with 2 elements, one of them a missing value.

```
x <- c(1, NA)
```

Now, what is its mean value?
Should we add all non missing values and divide by its **full length**, 2? Or should we divide by its **length after removal** of `NA`'s, just 1?

```
sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)/length(x)
#[1] 0.5
sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)/length(x[!is.na(x)])
#[1] 1
```

If `mean` is used, it's the latter that is computed.

```
mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 1
```

Comment: I thought of writing an answer with this example too--it's a good one. I was going to add a line of `sum(x, na.rm = TRUE) / length(x, na.rm = TRUE)` >> `Error!` to emphasize that not all common base R functions take the argument---it's not magic that works everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

`na.rm` is one of the arguments in a number of functions (of which you give some examples). To get information on the arguments of a function, run `?function`.

For instance, with `mean()`, running:

```
?mean
```

gives you the information you are looking for:

> na.rm: a logical value indicating whether NA values should be stripped before the computation proceeds.

By feeding this argument a logical value (`TRUE` or `FALSE`) you are choosing whether to strip the NAs or not while running the function. The default (also given by the `mean()` documentation) is `FALSE`.

And yes: R is case-sensitive.