# Calculating mean with NA value present in a data.frame using R

Tags: r, mean, na

I have a data.frame and would like to average a column where there is an NA present.

when performing the calculation I noticed that R cannot calculate the average, returning NA as a result.

OBS: I cannot remove the line with NA as it would remove other columns with values that interest me.

```
df1<-read.table(text="st    date    ph
1   01/02/2004  5
16  01/02/2004  6
2   01/02/2004  8
2   01/02/2004  8
2   01/02/2004  8
16  01/02/2004  6
1   01/02/2004  NA
1   01/02/2004  5
16  01/02/2004  NA
", sep="", header=TRUE)

df2<-df1%>%
 group_by(st, date)%>%
  summarise(ph=mean(ph))

View(df2)
```

out

[image]

my expectation was this result:

[image]

Comment: use `mean(ph, na.rm = TRUE)`, by defaut, `na.rm = FALSE` in `mean`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does na.rm=TRUE actually means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58443566/what-does-na-rm-true-actually-means)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `na.rm = TRUE`:

```
df2<-df1%>%
  group_by(st, date)%>%
  summarise(ph=mean(ph, na.rm = TRUE))

df2
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   st [3]
     st date          ph
  <int> <chr>      <dbl>
1     1 01/02/2004     5
2     2 01/02/2004     8
3    16 01/02/2004     6
```